# Why there are different oppacities for active and inactive icons in material design?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-icons

I am really wondering why there are different oppacities for active and inactive icons in [here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html#icons-system-icons):

[image]
And [here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-text-background-colors):

[image]
So I am confused in these two cases:

1- An inactive dark icon on a light background should have opacity 26% or 38%?

2- An inactive light icon on a dark background should have opacity 30% or 50%?

Comment: If you dive deeper into Google Material Design Guidelines you can find much more inconsistencies there. I'd recommend you to just stick with one choice for all your material apps :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why there are different oppacities for active and inactive icons

Because Material Design evolves and specs are updated inconsistently.

> So I am confused in these two cases

Since IMO this is more a topic of color than of icons and because I don't remember seeing the tables in second link, I'd say the second link is more up-to-date and stick to it.

Design library's `design_tint_password_toggle.xml` uses 54% and 38% which also suggests the second link is "correct".

For further reference as of 2016-11-09 these "correct" values are:

- Dark theme

  - Active: 100% white icon on dark background
  - Inactive: 50% white icon on dark background
- Light theme

  - Active: 54% black icon on light background
  - Inactive: 38% black icon on light background